# How to get variables from one Spring MVC Controller to Another

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I m novice to spring mvc. Could you please help me to design below.

I have newly written Controller A which is bind with model attribute “attribA” And new jsp is customerInformation.

Now I have existing Controller B which is bind with model attribute “attribB” and jsp is existing customerSummary which I will modify as per requirement where I want to display contents set by the user on previous jsp in model attribA.

How can I pass content or attributeA from new Controller A in an existing controller Controller B to show on second jsp customerSummary

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using "RedirectAttributes"

```
@PostMapping("/userWiseNewMenuPermission")
public ModelAndView setUserWiseNewMenuPermission(ModelAndView modelAndView,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("comfmMassg","Menu Permission Save Successful!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/userList?page=1");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

in this Post controller redirect to a get controller with a attribute name "comfmMassg" ......

```
@GetMapping("/userList")
public ModelAndView getMenu(ModelAndView modelAndView,@ModelAttribute("comfmMassg") String masg) {
    modelAndView.addObject("masg", masg); 
    modelAndView.setViewName("userList");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

this example work in spring boot ............

Comment: But can I have two @ModelAttribute in single method ? Because I already have one in that method